# Is there a way to retrieve a list of work items using the TFS API without resorting to querying its DB?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I'm writing an application to retrieve work items from a given project collection. Currently I have seen the standard practice is along the lines of the following:

```
WorkItemStore workitemstore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
string wiql = QueryToSelectWorkItems;
WorkItemCollection wic = workitemstore.Query(wiql);
```

Is there a way to retrieve the work items of a project without querying the database? E.g. A method that retrieves all work items of a team project collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the code above does not query the database directly. Querying the TFS DB's is unsupported. You are using WIQL (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306.aspx#operators) to query the API.

If you make your query "Select ID From WorkItems" you will get all items in the collection. Add "where [System.TeamProject] = 'myprojname'" to filter by project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query all work items across the team project collection, edit your work item query so that it doesn't have clauses to filter on the project, areas or iteration paths.